# Нужно ли ставить дефис после аббревиатуры-прилагательного?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, раздельно-дефис, дефис, аббревиатуры

В медицинской литературе некоторые прилагательные иногда сокращают до инициальных аббревиатур. При этом, судя по результатам поиска в Google, в одних и тех же сочетаниях аббревиатуры и существительного иногда после аббревиатуры ставят дефис, а иногда не ставят.

Например, перед разными существительными встречается сокращение "СС" в значении "сердечно-сосудистый": "СС система", "СС заболевание", "СС смерть" (то есть смерть вследствие нарушения работы сердечно-сосудистой системы). Другие примеры: "ГГН система" (гипоталамо-гипофизарно-надпочечниковая система), "ФК анализ" (фармакокинетический анализ).

Нужно ли в таких конструкциях ставить дефис после аббревиатуры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что об этом говорит "Грамота.ру" (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=272195)).

> Сложные слова, первая часть которых — аббревиатура, пишутся через дефис: *УКВ-передатчик*, *МВ-печь*, *ВИЧ-инфекция*, *ДНК-содержащий*. Поэтому верно: *ВЧ-вход*.

Как видите, не важно, образована аббревиатура существительными (ДНК-содержащий = содержащий дезоксирибонуклеиновую кислоту) или прилагательными (МВ-печь = микроволновая печь), — в обоих случаях НУЖЕН ДЕФИС. Поэтому верно: **СС-система**, **СС-заболевание**, **ГГН-система**, **ФК-анализ**.

Думается ещё, что при мысленном "раскрытии" аббревиатуры образующие её слова и "стыкующиеся" к ней слова должны формировать согласованное словосочетание, которое легко читается, иначе можно, как говорится, "залипнуть" в попытке расшифровать аббревиатуру. Поэтому написание *СС-смерть* (раскрывается как "сердечно-сосудистая смерть") представляется некорректным, правильнее было бы сказать: **смерть из-за проблем с СС-системой** или **нарушения в работе СС-системы, повлекшие смерть,** и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужен дефис, конечно. Ведь если писать полностью, его же тут не ставят. Обычное сочетание прилагательного с существительным, просто сокращённое.

Comment: Я очень сомневаюсь в том, что ваш ответ применим во всех случаях. Хотя бы потому, что если расшифровать "СС смерть", то получится "сердечно-сосудистая смерть", что абсурдно. Таким образом, по крайней мере "СС-смерть" требуется писать через дефис и воспринимать как профессиональную лексику.

Comment: @Nektoid Выражение "сердечно-сосудистая смерть" вполне используется в несокращенном виде.

Comment: @athlonusm в обычном (не профессиональном) языке "сердечно-сосудистая смерть" может значить только "смерть сердечно-сосудистой системы". Что абсурдно. В профессиональном языке "сердечно-сосудистая смерть" означает "смерть от сердечно-сосудистого заболевания".

Comment: @Nektoid: а по-моему, то и значит, что автор сказал. И дефис не как не помогает скорее именно так понять.

Comment: Можно сравнить:  Вопрос № 280453  
Какой из вариантов являются правильным - "необходимо провести тест на ДНК", "необходимо провести ДНК-тест" или "необходимо провести тест ДНК"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Корректно: ДНК-тест и тест ДНК.  Без дефиса запись   "СС система" выглядит странно.

Comment: Хм, что-то новенькое!

Comment: @Sharon В "ДНК-тест" слово "ДНК" – существительное. Хотя вот в этом вопросе упоминаются генно-модифицированные продукты с дефисным написанием: http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=216480

Comment: Да, интересный ответ (я как раз собираю материал по этой теме).  Здесь говорится о существительных в роли приложения, так что это одно и то же.  И используется общее правило для дефисного написания приложений. Но особенно интересен пример ГМ-продукты, так как аббревиатура там относится уже к словосочетанию на основе ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОГО (генетически модифицированные продукты), при этом существует стандартная аббревиатура ГМО  –  генетически модифицированный организм.

Comment: Из этого примера уже можно сделать вывод, что корректной будет запись через дефис – СС-заболевание. В то же время существует стандартная аббревиатура –  ССЗ.